# JavaScript: Enter value and submit text input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a JavaScript code to enter in a bunch of grades into an online grade book. The grade book is a table with inputs:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="12" 
class="grade-entry input--flush" tabindex="1" 
data-bind="visible:!$parent.assignment.useLetterGradingScheme,
value:gradeString, disable:showDetail || 
!$parent.permissions.AssignGrades || (isGradeApproved &amp;&amp;
!$parent.permissions.ChangeApprovedGrades), event:
{change:$parent.onChangeGrade,focus:$parent.onFocus}, 
attr:{'aria-label':'Grade for ' + sortableName}, 
css:{'animate-saving':saving, 'success':isGradeApproved}" 
aria-label="Grade for [last name], [first name] [middle initial]">
```

I have written a code that finds the correct input to put a students name in by accessing the *aria-label* attribute and comparing the first and last names. The code successfully goes through and enters the grades by:

```
input.value = 10.5;
```

However, the grade does not submit. When entering the grades manually, I have to first type the grade, and then press "Enter". After pressing "Enter", the color of the input box changes and the grade saves so that if I refresh the grade stays.

My code does not do this. After running the code, the input fields contain the grades, but when I refresh they all go away. So at the moment I have to go through, one by one, and click on the input and then press "Enter".

I have an array with all the inputs. I then find the correct index for the student. I have tried to simulate an Enter key press by:

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.which = 13; //choose the one you want
e.keyCode = 13;
$(inputs[i]).trigger(e);
```

where *inputs* is an array of all the input elements and *i* is the index of the correct input for the student.

Is there any way to do what I am trying to do?

**EDIT**
I forgot to mention; the input is not embedded inside a form or anything. It's just standalone inside a table row.

**EDIT**
It looks like it is an AJAX form. I'm not really familiar with AJAX, but I have added a small section of a function called `$.fn.ajaxSubmit` below that I found (only a small section because the whole function is really long). What is the parameter `options`? And if I have the `options` parameter correct, could I just called this function to submit it?

```
/**
 * ajaxSubmit() provides a mechanism for immediately submitting
 * an HTML form using AJAX.
 */
$.fn.ajaxSubmit = function(options) {
    /*jshint scripturl:true */

    // fast fail if nothing selected (http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/2752)
    if (!this.length) {
        log('ajaxSubmit: skipping submit process - no element selected');
        return this;
    }

    var method, action, url, $form = this;

    if (typeof options == 'function') {
        options = { success: options };
    }

    method = this.attr('method');
    action = this.attr('action');
    url = (typeof action === 'string') ? $.trim(action) : '';
    url = url || window.location.href || '';
    if (url) {
        // clean url (don't include hash vaue)
        url = (url.match(/^([^#]+)/)||[])[1];
    }

    options = $.extend(true, {
        url:  url,
        success: $.ajaxSettings.success,
        type: method || 'GET',
        iframeSrc: /^https/i.test(window.location.href || '') ? 'javascript:false' : 'about:blank'
    }, options);

    // hook for manipulating the form data before it is extracted;
    // convenient for use with rich editors like tinyMCE or FCKEditor
    var veto = {};
    this.trigger('form-pre-serialize', [this, options, veto]);
    if (veto.veto) {
        log('ajaxSubmit: submit vetoed via form-pre-serialize trigger');
        return this;
    }
    ....
    ....
```

Recall that with my current code, I find the actual `<Input>` object for each student and update the value. So could I call the above function with the specified `<Input>` and submit whatever value I just put in the `<Input>`?

**EDIT**
I have been trying to read up on AJAX. If I have the specified `<Input>` object (I'll call it `input1`, can I just say something like:

```
$(input1).ajaxSubmit();
```

Comment: Are you sure `input` in `input.value = 10.5;` is really an input element and not an array of inputs or some other type of object? Also, you don't need to emulate an enter for this input after you change its value.

Comment: Yes. All the numbers are inputed correctly. The problem is that they are not submitting. But there doesn't seem to be any submit value allowed for the input. The only way I know how to submit grades is by pressing Enter.

Comment: @Joe jsfiddle with your example will be very helpful, because I can't get how you can submit something without form just with html. Please, add everything related from your code here.

Comment: 2 ideas. 1)input.value="10.5" since value is a GradeString. [probably automatically cast and not going to help] and 2) invoke the change event yourself, manually.

Comment: One _very_ important point worth considering-- when you are hitting `<enter>` when inputting the data manually-- is the page doing a full page refresh?  Like if you had submitted a non-AJAXed form?

Comment: @anied No. The page is not refreshing. I have been looking at the javascript code; I think it is an AJAX form. I'm not entirely sure how to use AJAX. I have added a small section of the code to the question from a function called `$.fn.ajaxSubmit`.

Comment: I see a handler for the change event in your input element. As suggested by @JeremyKahan, you could trigger that event: `$(inputs[i]).trigger("change");`.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Oh!!!!!!!! Thanks so much!! I didn't quite understand what Jeremy Kahan meant by that. Thanks for the clarification. It works!! I don't know how to award you or him best answer since these are just comments. Feel free to submit an answer and I will select it as best answer. Otherwise, in a couple of days I will write it as an answer so the question is not though to be left unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the input control triggers the `change` event, which is then processed by `$parent.onChangeGrade`. Instead of sending a `keypress` event programmatically, you can trigger the `change` event directly:

```
$(inputs[i]).trigger("change");
```

Comment: Thanks for running with that idea @ConnorsFan. I was guessing, and I am glad you were able to bring it to fruition.